# Rig a BJT to drive a fan

Tags: bjt, fan

I wanted to see if i could use a BJT to power a small pc fan. I have a potentiometer into the base but how would I wire the fan so that depending on the base current it would adjust the current to the fan?

Comment: If you want a particular motor speed you want to set the _voltage_ applied to the motor, not the current.

Comment: As Kevin says it's voltage you should be after. Switching the transistor on and off through a PWM signal would vary the average voltage applied across the fan and hence vary its speed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIwjWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is not strictly necessary but it reduces the chances of you frying something.

Q1 acts as an emitter follower to buffer the pot voltage. Q1 may need a heat sink if the fan draws a lot of current. R2 enforces a minimum voltage setting- since most fans won't start if the voltage is too low. Adjust as required (probably upwards). The circuit as shown gives about 2V to 11V+ at the fan.

Comment: and tiny FETs in fan may get hot if fan is stalled, depending on design choices.

Comment: I didn't copy the exact circuit, i used a 4.7uf cap, disregarded R1 and played around with different values for R2. Also the variable resistor I am using is a MCP4131-104 (100k) chip. The chip is powered at 5V and I can vary the resistor, though what I am finding is if the base is at 5v, collector at 12, the emitter stays about 4.6V which isn't the 12V I need to fully power the fan. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an op-amp (powered from +12) as a non-inverting amplifier to amplify and buffer the output voltage from your digital pot. Eg. 10K/15K would give you a gain of +(1 + 15/10) = 2.5. Or use a digital pot that can work with your logic levels and an analog supply of +12. Or replace the whole thing with a  PWM.

Comment: @Transistor - If the base is at 5 volts, you will necessarily drop several tenths of a volt through the emitter-base junction of the transistor, and the load will always be less than 5 volts. "Any suggestions?" Yep. Raise the base voltage to nearly 12 volts. Can't do that with your digital pot? Then you're going to have to use something else. Spehro's suggested circuit did not envision you using a 5-volt digipot, and your substitution will not do what you want. Try replacing with a real, non-digital pot in the suggested circuit and see what happens.